# Easiest way to dynamically set <meta> in React?

Tags: reactjs

I’m trying to dynamically set `<meta property="og:url` tags on a per page basis, so scrapers like Facebook can pickup the meta data on specific posts.  The Facebook scraper, unlike Google, does not run your javascript.  So the only way to do this is pre-build or server side.  Otherwise I could just use `react-helmet`, but that operates after page load.

I built my react app using `create-react-app`, and now it seems like I have to go through a HUGE hassle to set it up with server side rendering for just this one thing.  What’s the most pain free way to dynamically set my meta tags?

Comment: Definitely pre build or server side render. I wouldn’t trust the data if it was set by client side code. It’s one of those awkward situations that can’t be avoided. SSR isn’t necessary difficult to adapt to if you don’t have a lot of code to migrate | edge towards being SSR compatible (mostly react router if you use it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up implementing SSR with this approach https://medium.com/@cereallarceny/server-side-rendering-with-create-react-app-fiber-react-router-v4-helmet-redux-and-thunk-275cb25ca972